# I am submitting a form using jquery ajax ,the is submitting but it not displaying in page .

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am submitting a form using jquery ajax ,the form is submitting but it is not displaying in page . 
In console networks there form data there status 200 ok.
No error can't solve this problem help pls.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Also see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: seems like you are ajax newbie, follow this https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/, pretty straightforward